# Cartesian Coordinate System and 2d arrays

Tags: c, arrays, cartesian-coordinates

I'm doing this c program to print a Cartesian coordinate system with points in it, by using the x and y coordinates from standard input, but I'm struggling with this code.
I'm not using some graphics libraries but 2d arrays.
The output should be look something like this:[image] When i replace in
Field[y][x] x and y with some numbers (2 for y and 1 for x), it gives me the above result.
How can I fix this code in order to print the points on the graph?
Thanks all.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS  5
#define COLS  5
#define N     25

int main()
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int x;
    int y;
    int Points;
    int Field[ROWS][COLS];

    for(i = 0; i < ROWS; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++){
            Field[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    printf("Enter the number of points: \n");
    scanf(" %d", &Points);
    if(Points != N){
        printf("Enter the x and y coordinates of the points: \n");
        for(i = 0, j = 0; i < Points, j < Points; i++, j++)
        {
            printf("(X%d, Y%d) = ", j, i);
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("(%d, %d)", &x, &y);
            Field[y][x] = 1;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("The inserted number exceeds the maximum possible number \n");
    }

    for(i = ROWS - 1; i > 0; i--)
        printf("%d\n \n \n", i);

    for(i = ROWS-1; i >= 0; i--){
      for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++){
        if(Field[i][j] == 0)
           printf("");
        else{
           switch(j){
            case 0:
                printf("o");
                break;
            case 1:
                printf("\t o");
                break;
            case 2:
                printf(" \t \t o");
                break;
            case 3:
                printf(" \t \t \t o");
                break;
            case 4:
                printf(" \t \t \t \t o");
                break;
           }
         }
       }
        printf("\n \n");
    }   

    for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        printf("%d\t", j);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you should know is when you print a line moved to the next line you can't go back to the passed line. So you should begin printing from the highest raw of your 2d-array. Then you should start checking from the beginning of that raw whether is a point or not, if found print it otherwise move forward. You don't need a switch statement for spacing, you can implement it from the `for` loop.

This gives the program that you need. I also corrected your scanning `for` loop. For a comma separated input you need to put *only the comma* in the scanning string. And when giving the conditions for the for loop use operators `&& <,>,<=,>=,!=`, this `for(i = 0, j = 0; i < Points, j < Points; i++, j++)` is not a effective code look at my code how I've corrected it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS  5
#define COLS  5
#define N     25

int main()
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int x;
    int y;
    int Points;
    int Field[ROWS][COLS];

    for(i = 0; i < ROWS; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++){
            Field[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    printf("Enter the number of points: \n");
    scanf(" %d", &Points);
    if(Points != N){
        printf("Enter the x and y coordinates of the points: \n");
        for(i = 0, j = 0; i < Points&&j < Points; i++, j++)
        {
            printf("(X%d, Y%d) = ",j,i);
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%d,%d", &x, &y);
            Field[y][x] = 1;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("The inserted number exceeds the maximum possible number \n");
    }

    for(int i=ROWS-1;i>0;i--){
        printf("%d", i);
        for(int j=0;j<COLS;j++){

            if(Field[i][j]==1){
                printf("o");
            }
            printf("\t");

        }
        printf("\n\n\n");

    }  

    for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        printf("%d\t", j);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope I undestand what u need.

```
 int main()
    {
        int i;
        int j;
        int x;
        int y;
        int Points;
        int Field[ROWS][COLS];

        for(i = 0; i < ROWS; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++){
                Field[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }

        /** rest of your code*/

        for(i = ROWS-1; i >= 0; i--){
            printf("%d", i);
            for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++){
                if(Field[i][j] == 0){
                    printf("");
                }
                else{
                    switch(j){
                        case 0:
                            printf("\t o");
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            printf("\t \t o");
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            printf(" \t \t \t o");
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            printf(" \t \t \t \t o");
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            printf(" \t \t \t \t \t o");
                            break;
                    }

                }
            }
            printf("\n \n");
        }   
        printf("\t");
        for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++){
            printf("%d\t", j);
        }
        return 0;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you can use the struct in c to store the coordinates of each points. It will be useful if you want to do the other things with the points.

```
typedef struct {
  int x;
  int y;
}coordinates;
```

In your code

```
for(i = 0, j = 0; i < Points, j < Points; i++, j++)
        {
            printf("(X%d, Y%d) = ", j, i);
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("(%d, %d)", &x, &y);
            Field[y][x] = 1;
        }
```

Using two variables is not necessary, because the value of `i` is always equal to `j`. So, you can use only `i` is enough.

```
for(i = 0; i < Points; i++)
{
     printf("(X%d, Y%d) = ",i,i);
     fflush(stdin);
     scanf("%d,%d", &x, &y);
     Field[y][x] = 1;
}
```

One more thing, you should use `(i < Points) && (j < Points)` instead of `i < Points, j < Points`.

If you use 2d array, the code of @Neminda Prabhashwara seems ok. But if you want to use the struct as i mentioned above, you can see my code (it may not be optimized). It just shows my idea.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ROWS  5
#define COLS  5
#define N     25

typedef struct {
  int x;
  int y;
}coordinates;

void sorting_coord(coordinates * a, int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++){
        for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++){
            if(a[i].y > a[j].y){
                coordinates tg = a[i];
                            a[i] = a[j];
                            a[j] = tg;        
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    int Points;
    coordinates * coord;

    printf("Enter the number of points: \n");
    scanf(" %d", &Points);
    coord = malloc(Points * sizeof(coordinates));
    if(Points < N && Points >= 0){
        printf("Enter the x and y coordinates of the points: \n");
        for(i = 0; i < Points; i++)
        {
            printf("(X%d, Y%d) = ", i, i);
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%d, %d", &coord[i].x, &coord[i].y);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("The inserted number exceeds the maximum possible number \n");
    }

    sorting_coord(coord, Points);
    int temp;
    for(i = ROWS - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        temp = 0;
        printf("%d", i);
        for (int k = 0; k < Points; k++) {
            if(coord[k].y == i ) {
                for (int j = 0; j < (coord[k].x - temp); j++) {
                    printf("\t");
                }
                if (coord[k].x != 0)
                    printf("°");
                temp = coord[k].x;
            }
      }

      printf("\n\n\n");
    }


    for(int j = 0; j < COLS; j++){
        printf("%d\t", j);
    }

    return 0;

}
```